# How to send one email reminder, to each staff, that includes client names and phone #s if the client call back date is today?

Tags: vba, outlook

```
Staff_Name   Client_FName   Client_LName   Client_Phone  Call_Back_Date  Staff_Email
```

From Excel, I send email reminders to staff to call their clients that are due for a call back today. I figured out how for each client.

If the staff has 10 clients due for call backs today, I want to compile the list and send just one email with all of their clients' names and phone #s in one email.

```
Sub CallReminder1()
Dim OutlookApp As Object
Dim objMail As Object
Dim nextcalldate As Date
Dim datetoday As Date
Dim x As Long

For x = 2 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(2))

    nextcalldate = Cells(x, 5).Value
    datetoday = Date

    If nextcalldate <= datetoday Then
        Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set objMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        objMail.To = Cells(x, 6).Value

        With objMail
            .Subject = "Calls to make Today"
            .Body = Cells(x, 1) & ": " & Cells(x, 2) & " " & Cells(x, 3) & ", " & Cells(x, 4)
            .Send
        End With
    End If
Next

Set OutlookApp = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: To clarify, you want to send a single email with a list of clients, instead of one email per client? Generate a string with the list of clients and their details. If the string is not empty, set the string as the `Body` of the (single) email and send. But please describe what it is you have tried, and why it hasn't worked.

Comment: Yes, but I don't even know how to go about doing the single email with the list of clients. I was only able to figure out how to send as separate emails (see code above).  FYI: I haven't used macros, vba in 10+ years, so I'm basically a novice.

Comment: Works Beautifully! Thanks so much!

Comment: 1 more question: for the above exercise I had the email for each staff in this same worksheet, listed multiple times, every time the staff name appears.  What if, instead for efficiency, I had a separate worksheet (StaffEmails) in that same workbook that contained the Staff_Name and Staff_Email and wanted to lookup the staff's email?  You've been a great help so far! thanks

Comment: That kind of structure would have other benefits, specifically you wouldn't have to worry that the same staff member might have different emails on different rows. But as long as you're working in Excel (as opposed to a database management system such as Access), and don't see any performance issues, I would say it's not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary object, keyed on the staff name.  Loop over the data and collect the calls for each person, then loop over the dictionary keys and create the mails.

```
Sub CallReminder1()

    Const olMailItem As Long = 0
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim objMail As Object
    Dim nextcalldate As Date
    Dim staff As String, msg As String
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim x As Long, k

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    'collect all of the due calls, arranged by staff name
    For x = 2 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(2))
        nextcalldate = Cells(x, 5).Value
        If nextcalldate <= Date Then
            staff = Cells(x, 6).Value
            msg = Cells(x, 1) & ": " & Cells(x, 2) & " " & _
                Cells(x, 3) & ", " & Cells(x, 4) & vbCrLf
            'add to any existing message for this staff member
            If dict.Exists(staff) Then
                dict(staff) = dict(staff) & msg
            Else
                dict(staff) = msg
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    'loop over the dictionary keys (staff)
    '  and create a mail per staff
    For Each k In dict.keys
        Set objMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        objMail.To = NameToEmail(k) '<<< EDIT
        With objMail
            .Subject = "Calls to make Today"
            .Body = dict(k)
            .Send
        End With
    Next k

    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
    Set objMail = Nothing
End Sub

Function NameToEmail(staffName)
    Dim m
    m = Application.VLookup(staffName, _
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StaffEmails").Range("A2:B1000"), 2, False)
    NameToEmail = IIf(IsError(m), "???", m) 'return "???" if no match
End Function
```

Comment: The first time a given staff is encountered, what happens in `dict(staff) = dict(staff) & msg`? Isn't it some kind of error to access the dictionary value of a non-existent key?

Comment: Also, this works until you have two staff members with the same name.

Comment: @ZevSpitz - you are correct about the error - fixed above.  As for two staff with the same name: OP uses the staff column to address the email so I'm assuming that's unique to one person...

Comment: 1 more question: for the above exercise I had the email for each staff in this same worksheet, listed multiple times, every time the staff name appears. What if, instead for efficiency, I had a separate worksheet (StaffEmails) in that same workbook that contained the Staff_Name and Staff_Email and wanted to lookup the staff's email by their name if column 1 (as long as the Name was unique)? You've been a great help so far! thanks

Comment: VERY helpful. I changed the "???" if it can't find an email to set it to a default email, so that person whose email is designated as the default email will at least get notice that calls were due. Thanks so much!